# Multiple users facing DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cpanel, whm

Many of my application users started facing `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` issue intermittently. I learned that this could be possibly due to a DNS issue on users' computers or home networks, but it cannot be the case with most users.

My application is hosted on AWS and users in Norway are complaining about the application unavailability issue. When I tried connecting to multiple users, it was throwing `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error
Surprisingly when I pinged IP from user system, it was returning response however pining domain was not working.
I also tried nslookup using domain but no response returned.
In my understanding this is not local computer issue as application works fine most of time but breaks intermittently with referred issue.
Any insight into troubleshooting the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is some issue with DNS settings for your domain, can you share the real domain/host name

Comment: here is domain admin.abel.fit